What do the hieroglyphs say on Reaper’s mythic gun skins?

Does anyone know what the hieroglyphs say on Reaper’s guns when he is wearing the mythic skin Anubis?


If you have suggestions on how to improve my answer so you don't feel indecisive, please speak up!

@Malady Quoting Reddit is fine, but fortunately Equal-Acanthisitta51 actually links to their source of information: Nicole Lesar AKA ancientegyptblog7 AKA The Self-Taught Egyptologist.  In particular, their relevant blog posts include: 1. “Words Spoken By” in Hieroglyphs and 2. Uncommon Variant of Anubis.  I think adding a quotes or links to these pages would make your answer stronger.

@ElementsInSpace - Thanks for the tip! Egyptian dictionaries are annoying to look through, at least this one is, https://archive.org/details/hierodict/page/61/mode/1up but maybe that's just because it's online. At any rate, tracked down Anpu, now to do "t'et dn".

Same question on Reddit gives responses like this one by Equal-Acanthisitta51 2 months ago:

did some research, and i believe it says “Words spoken by Anubis” or maybe just “Anubis.” ” ” is a word for Anubis, and “” translates to “Words spoken by...” or “Speech by…” but is almost always followed by the name of a god.

The second occurrence of the flowering reed hieroglyph shown below, is the start of "Anubis", and the glyphs before that are “Words spoken by...” / “Speech by…”

For more authoritative sources, if you don't trust anything you can dig up by searching the phrases yourself...
Looking through EA Wallis Budge dictionaries, since the other answer finds that authoritative:
First character in the dictionary has been found but not whole phrase, still, very "talky".
Wikipedia as well says that " " is Anubis, citing Leprohon 1990, p. 164, citing Fischer 1968, p. 84 and Lapp 1986, pp. 8–9, but there's also the left middle "Anpu" of that dictionary link.

Could you add a screenshot of the symbols? It seems my OS/fonts cannot render them and I'm seeing squares with random numbers inside.

@Clockwork - Added the important split point. Gonna see if I can do better.

@Clockwork Here’s a screenshot of the quote.

@Clockwork I’ve put links on the symbols in my answer below. Can you tell me if you think that makes it accessible enough, or should I change it (perhaps by embedding tiny images)?

@ElementsInSpace I think either would do but having links instead does help in not cluttering the answers too much. Thank you to both of you.

Saith …
The first word(s)  , occurs frequently in The Egyptian Book of the Dead. This is transliterated as t’eṭ dn in EA Wallis Budge’s publication on this work.*
Budge’s translates it as either “saith he”, or simply “saith” (sometimes “speaketh”) when the name of the speaker follows immediately, or occasionally “hath spoken” (see below):



… Anubis
The second word, , is one form for the name of the god of the underworld: Anubis.  The first part  is phonemic (representing the sounds in the word) for Ȧnpu, whereas the  glyph is a determinative symbol that isn’t pronounced.
In the text, various forms of this name occur, differing only by the determinative symbol(s) at the end, these include:
, , , and  (see below):



I was even able to find a couple of instances in the text with these words in conjunction:



* EA Wallis Budge’s The Egyptian Book of the Dead — (The Papyrus of Ani) Egyptian Text Transliteration and Translation, reprinted in 2017 by Dover Publishing Inc., (1st ed. published in 1967, originally published in 1895).

